# Why Cayley table representation?

Tags: group-theory, algorithms

I have seen in many times group is given as a input(for algorithms) as a Cayley table form instead of generator and relators. What is the advantage of the Cayley table representation as compare to other representations of the group?

Comment: A Cayley table makes it easy to look up the result of the operation on any two group elements

Comment: Nearly all of the fundamental algorithmic questions in group theory have been proved to be theoretically undecidable when the input is a finite group presentation.

Comment: @DerekHolt I would love to hear more about that — do you have any particular examples on hand?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Serious question, did you just punch your keyboard for the relators or did you have something specific in mind?

Comment: @Babelfish No, these are two well-known exercises. I write it down below, although Derek's comment is more than enough. The first one has been solved at this site - have a look.

Comment: In any case what you write is not true. No sensible algorithm for finite groups takes a Cayley table as input. That would restrict its application to moderately small groups. Serious algorithms take generators of a subgroups of $S_n$ for some $n$, or generating matrices as input. Certain types of presentations are suitable for somputing with solvable groups however.

Answer (score 2):

Derek Holt's comment is an answer. Usually it is very hard for a given presentation of a group to conclude certain properties about the group. Theoretically, one can often show that it is undecidable in general, e.g., whether or not the given group is the trivial one, or not.
Here are two well-known examples, which can be decided, but which already show that this might be not so convenient.

**Question 1 (easier)**: Is the group with presentation $\langle a,b\mid ab^2a^{-1}b^{-3}=ba^2b^{-1}a^{-3}=e\rangle$ the trivial group or not?

**Question 2 (harder)**: Has the group with presentation $\langle a,b\mid a^{2}=b^{3}=(ab)^{13}=[a,b]^{5}=[a,bab]^{4}=(ababababab^{-1})^{6}=e\rangle$ more than $17000000$ elements, or not? Is it a simple group or not?

Comment: Yes,yes, and yes (I'm a yes man!) (Coset enumeration with the subgroup $\langle ab \rangle$ works for Question 2.)